# vuejs/vuetify : generated list of dialog's close manually

Tags: vue.js, dialog, modal-dialog, vuetify.js

I have a list of label and vue-color (`compact-picker`) like this

[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Sr0.png)

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-tile
            v-for="sport in filterSports(conso.sports)"
            :key="sport.number"
            @click="sportSelected(sport.number)"
            :class="{'d-none': displaySport(sport)}">
        <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-dialog width="300">
                <v-btn
                        flat
                        slot="activator"
                        color="grey">
                    <v-icon
                            :color="findIconColor(sport.number).color">lens
                    </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-card>
                    <v-card-title
                            class="subheading grey lighten-2"
                            primary-title>
                        Color picker
                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-card-text>
                        <compact-picker v-model="colors"
                                        @input="setDepColor($event, sport.number)"></compact-picker>
                    </v-card-text>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-layout
                                align-center
                                justify-end>
                            <v-btn @click="closeDialog">
                                <v-icon class="mr-1">done</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </v-layout>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-dialog>

        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content
                :class="{ 'grey--text': isSelected(sport)}">
            {{sport.label}}.
        </v-list-tile-content>

    </v-list-tile>
</v-list>
```

How can i close "this" dialog on click btn with `@click=closeDialog` ?

When i click outside the dialog, this dialog closes alone.

I tried with `v-model`, but when i click on icon for open dialog, vue open all dialogs instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the same variable for all `v-dialog` and that's why they are all started at the same time.

You need on var for each

```
<v-dialog width="300" v-model="sport.show">
```

and then in on the close button

```
<v-btn @click="sport.show = false">
```

Comment: Amazing work ! thanks, it gives me a lot of possibilities for the future !